# Make it simple in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

Here is my squlite  statement :

```
select code ,  
case  when  (max(close)-min(close))/min(close)<0.1 then "grade1" 
when  (max(close)-min(close))/min(close) <0.2  then  "grade2"
when  (max(close)-min(close))/min(close) <0.3  then  "grade3"
else "grade4"  end  as  type;
```

The  `(max(close)-min(close))/min(close)`  was  used three times ,how can i make my query statement  more simple?

Comment: There may be a way to do this that I'm not aware of, but the obvious way would be to use a variable, which unfortunately sqlite does not support. So, I'm not sure if it's possible to simplify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the computation into a subquery:

```
SELECT code,
       CASE WHEN CloseRatio < 0.1 THEN 'grade1'
            WHEN CloseRatio < 0.2 THEN 'grade2'
            WHEN CloseRatio < 0.3 THEN 'grade3'
            ELSE                       'grade4'
       END AS type
FROM (SELECT code,
             (MAX(close) - MIN(close)) / MIN(close) AS CloseRatio
      FROM MyTable);
```